# Checking whether columns are filled in based on values in other columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({1: [2, 4, 0, 0, 2], 2: [5, 6, 0, 0, 34], 3:[6,12,0,3,0], 4:[6,7,0,7,0]})

   1   2   3  4
0  2   5   6  6
1  4   6  12  7
2  0   0   0  0
3  0   0   3  7
4  2  34   0  0
```

I would like to check row by row that if there is any non-zero element in columns 1 or 2, then there is also at least one non-zero element in columns 3 or 4; if elements in columns 1 or 2 are both zero, then columns 3 and 4 should also both be zero.

So with the example dataframe above I would like to have  list like this:

```
[(0, True), (1, True), (2, True), (3, False), (4, False)]
```

Comment: You have only 4 row but output list length is *5*. how?

Comment: why would index 2 return True?

Comment: @anky_91 If  elements in columns 1 or 2 are empty then colums 3 and 4 should be empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can build this up with a fairly straightforward list comprehension that follows the specified rules:

If both columns 0 and 1 are `0` and both columns 2 and 3 are `0` -or-
   either columns 0 and 1 are non-`0` and either columns 2 and 3 are non-`0` then it will return `True` for that row, otherwise `False`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({1: [2, 4, 0, 0, 2], 2: [5, 6, 0, 0, 34], 3: [6, 12, 0, 3, 0], 4: [6, 7, 0, 7, 0]})
x = [(i, (all(df.iloc[i, 0:2] == 0) and (all(df.iloc[i, 2:4] == 0)) or (
            any(df.iloc[i, 0:2] != 0) and (any(df.iloc[i, 2:4] != 0))))) for i in df.index]
```

Returns

```
[(0, True), (1, True), (2, True), (3, False), (4, False)]
```